# Durek Probability pg. 175 Integration & probability question

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution

I cannot understand why the following expression is true

$\operatorname{Pr}(A \in D, B \leq t)=\int_{0}^{t} f_{B}(z) \operatorname{Pr}(A \in D \mid B=z) \mathrm{d} z$ (I)

From my limited understanding, using rules of probability:

$\operatorname{Pr}(A \in D, B \leq t)=  \operatorname{Pr}(A \in D| B \leq t) * \operatorname{Pr}(B \leq t)  =  \operatorname{Pr}(A \in D| B \leq t) * \int_{0}^{t} f_{B}(z) \mathrm{d} z$ (II)

where $f_{B}(z)$ is the pdf.

Is (II) correct? If yes, then how do I go from (II) to (I)?
If not, then why is (I) correct? Is there a derivation?

Comparing both equations, feels like in (I), the conditional term is somehow pulled in the integration and the $\leq t$ is changed to =. Can someone explain why (I) is correct mathematically?

I need to get to (I) to understand a proof.

This is also on pg. 175 of Durek Probability in the expansion of $P(N_t = n)$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both are in a sense correct, though in (II) I do not know how you might calculate $\Pr(A \in D\mid  B \leq t)$ except as $\frac{\Pr(A \in D, B \leq t)}{\Pr(B \leq t)}$.

Comment: @Henry I need to understand why $(I)$ is correct. Looking at both equations, feels like in (I), the conditional term is somehow pulled in the integration and the ≤ is changed to =. Do you have any mathematical explanation for why $(I)$ is correct wrt these thoughts?

Comment: Try a finite discrete example, such as throwing two fair dice (red and blue).  What is the probability that the red die is odd and that the sum is less than or equal to $4$?  One approach could be to look at each of the sums of $2$ and $3$ and $4$ and work out the conditional probabilities in each case so you get $\Pr(\text{red die odd and sum is }\le 4)$ $=\sum\limits_{B=2}^4 \Pr(\text{red die odd} \mid \text{sum is } B)\Pr(\text{sum is } B)$ $= 1 \times \frac1{36}+\frac12 \times \frac2{36}+\frac23 \times \frac3{36}=\frac4{36}$ $=\frac19$.  Your (I) is the continuous version of this.

Comment: There is nothing special about the event $\{A\in D\}$. In general, for any event $E$, any absolutely continuous random variable $X$, and any Borel set $B$, we have $$\operatorname{Pr}(E, X\in B)=\int_{B} \operatorname{Pr}(E \mid X = x) f_X(x) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$ This is nothing but a continuum analog of the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability): If $X$ is discrete, then $$\operatorname{Pr}(E, X\in B) = \sum_{x\in B} \operatorname{Pr}(E, X = x) = \sum_{x\in B} \operatorname{Pr}(E\mid X=x)\operatorname{Pr}(X = x). $$

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks for the comment. I think the problem is that I have never seen $\operatorname{Pr}(E, X \in B)$ written as that rather $\operatorname{Pr}(E) = \sum_{x \in B} \operatorname{Pr}(E, X=x)$ . So the other variable wasn't present in the LHS itself. How are the two equivalent?

Comment: @Henry thanks for the reply. Looking at Sangchul's comment, I think my issue is that I have seen $\operatorname{Pr}(E)$ written as $\operatorname{Pr}(E)=\sum_{x \in B} \operatorname{Pr}(E, X=x)$ rather than $\operatorname{Pr}(E, X \in B)$. How are the 2 equivalent?

Comment: Note that, if $F_1, F_2, \ldots $ are mutually disjoint events, then $$\sum_n \operatorname{Pr}(F_n)=\operatorname{Pr}(\cup_n F_n). $$ Now if $X$ is a discrete random variable taking values $x_1, x_2, \ldots$, and if $E$ is an event, then by choosing $F_n=E\cap\{X=x_n\}$, we have $$\sum_n \operatorname{Pr}(E, X=x_n)=\operatorname{Pr}(\cup_n (E\cap\{X=x_n\}))=\operatorname{Pr}(E\cap(\cup_n \{X=x_n\}))=\operatorname{Pr}(E).$$ In general, if you restrict the sum over all $n$ for which $x_n \in B$ holds, then we get the formula in my previous comment.